# How to resolve "Config must be specified for the HighchartsChart component" error?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Before inserting

```
 <ReactHighcharts config={barchartdata}></ReactHighcharts> 

<div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
    <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header d-flex">
            <h5 className="card-title mr-auto"> Team Wise Total Revenue</h5>
        </div>                      
        <div className="card-body">
            <figure>

            </figure>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

let barchartdata = this.state.reports.chartslist.charts[0];

console.log("databarchart", this.state.reports.chartslist.charts[0]);

I can able to get the data.

```
   <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
<div className="card">
    <div className="card-header d-flex">
        <h5 className="card-title mr-auto"> Team Wise Total Revenue</h5>
    </div>                      
    <div className="card-body">
        <figure>
            <ReactHighcharts config={barchartdata}></ReactHighcharts>
        </figure>
    </div>      
</div>
```

[barchartdata has following response too:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqNuI.png)

[config must be specified error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueYrY.png)

Comment: config must be specified for the HighchartsChart component ::: i am getting this error

Comment: @ewolden i have edited the error issue is not that mainly, getting config error

Comment: check this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-space-between-bar-b2gnwg?file=index.js)